# Mailto works in firefox, but not in Chrome and sometimes in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser

I am a beginner in HTML/CSS/JavaScript. I am doing a final project and I have everything done, including the mobile pages too. In my web page I created a email form that a user can fill out if they wish to contact me. Once they click the "Submit" button, the client side email application (outlook or equivalent) will open and populate the fields with the information that was entered on the web page. This works fine in Mozilla Firefox, but when i switch over to anything else, I get mixed results. Sometimes Inter Explorer will work, then all of sudden it wont. Chrome will work randomly once, and then never again. Can someone please tell me what its is I am missing? Here is my code that follows:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Welcome To MyHomepage</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../IMG/clipart.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/main.css">
<script src="../../js/Javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<header>

<div id="leftheader">
<img id="leftpic"src="../../IMG/datad.jpg" alt="Data Defense">
</div>
<div id="rightheader">
<img id="righthpic"src="../../IMG/datad.jpg" alt="Data Defense">
</div>
<div id="midhead">
<h2>Welcome to the Home Page of My Name</h2>
<h3 class="shadow">Security Is Everyone's Responsibility!!!</h3>
<h4 class="contact"><a href="../../HTML/contact.html">Contact Me Now!!!</a></h4>
</div>

</header>


    <main>
<div class="backcolor">

    <ul class="navbar"><!--top-level-menu-->
      <li id="firstnav" ><a href="../../index.html">Home</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-content"><!--2nd-level-menu-->
        <li><a href="../../HTML/JQUERY/mobile.html">JQUERY</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>

  <li id="secnav"><a href="../../HTML/experience.html">Experience</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-content"><!--2nd-level-menu-->
        <li><a href="../Experience/CExperience.html">Civilian</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Experience/MExperience.html">Military</a></li>
     </ul>
     </li>

  <li id="thirdnav" ><a href="../../HTML/about.html">About Me</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-content"><!--2nd-level-menu-->
        <li><a href="../../HTML/Aboutme/Travels.html">My Travels</a>

            <ul class="dropdown-extension"><!--3rd-level-menu-->
                <li><a href="../../HTML/Aboutme/Travels/Travels.html">CONUS</a></li>
                <li><a href="../../HTML/Aboutme/Travels/TravelsOCO.html">OCONUS</a></li>

            </ul>

        </li>
        <li><a href="../../HTML/Aboutme/Education.html">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="../../HTML/Aboutme/Hobbies.html">Hobbies</a></li>
        <li><a href="../../HTML/Aboutme/Special.html">Sepcial Projects<a/></li>
        <li><a href="../../HTML/Aboutme/Soceities.html">Soceities</a></li>
    </ul>

  </li>

  <li id="fourthnav"><a href="../../HTML/volunteer.html">Volunteer Work</a></li>

  <li id="fifthnav"><a href="../../HTML/skills.html">Skills</a></li>

  <li id="sixthnav"><a href="../../HTML/goals.html">Goals</a>

        <ul class="dropdown-content"><!--2nd-level-menu-->
            <li><a href="../../HTML/Goals/GoalsST.html">Short Term</li>
            <li><a href="../../HTML/Goals/GoalsLT.html">Long Term</li>
        </ul>
  </li>

   <li id="lastnav" class="active"><a href="../../HTML/contact.html">Contact Me</a>
        <ul id="lastnav"class="dropdown-content"><!--2nd-level-menu-->

            <li><a href="../../HTML/Contact/phone.html">Phone</a></li>

            <li><a href="../../HTML/Contact/email.html" class="sub-active">Email</a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-extension1"><!--3rd-level-menu-->
                        <li><a href="../../HTML/Contact/webemail.html">Web Email<a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </li>

</ul> 
</div>

<div id="mainsec">

   <div id="leftsec">
   this is a test
   </div>

<div id="rightsec">
   this is a test
   </div>

      <div id="midsec">
     <div class="contact-section1">

     <h3 id="quest1">
     How to Contact me?
     </h3>

     <h4  id="answer1" class="shadow1">
    You can contact me by filling out the information below.
    Please give me 24-72 hours to reply back.
    </h4>

    <h4>Please note, clicking "Submit" will open the email application
on your device!</h4>

    </div>

    <div id="body">

     <div id="section">
     <form id="email_form" name="email_form" action= "sent/sent.html" method="get">

    <label for="email_address1"id="label">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email_address1" name="email_address1"</label>
    <span id="email_address1_error">*</span><br><br>

    <label for="emal_address2"id="label">Re=Enter Email Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email_address2" name="emaill_address2">
    <span id="email_address2_error">*</span><br><br>

    <label for="name"id="label">Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <span id="name_error">*</span><br><br>

    <label for="subject"id="label">Subject:</label>
    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">
    <span id="subject_error">*</span><br><br>

    <label for="message" id="label">Message:</label>
    <textarea type="text" id="message"  tabindex="3"></textarea>
    <span id="message_error">*</span><br><br>

    <label id="label">&nbsp;</label>

    <input type="button" id="join_list" value="Submit"> 

    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <h4 class="disclaimer" id="shadowtext">If you do not wish to use your email application, please <a href="../../HTML/Contact/webemail.html" id="shadowtext">click here</a>
to go to the web page email application.</h4>
    </div>

     <div class="contactemail-section2">

    </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    </main>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2016, My Name All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </footer>
    </html>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var $=function(id){

    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var joinList=function (){
    var emailAddress1=$("email_address1").value;
    var emailAddress2=$("email_address2").value;
    var Name=$("name").value;
    var Subject=$("subject").value;
    var Message=$("message").value;
    var isValid=true;
    var Toemail="I have removed the email address for this post";
    var CCemail="I have removed the email address for this post"";


 Message=Message+"%0D%0A"+"%0D%0A"+"%0D%0A"+"From,"+" %0D%0A"+ Name + "%0D%0A"+emailAddress1;


     if(emailAddress1=="")
    {
        $("email_address1_error").firstChild.nodeValue="This feild is required.";
        isValid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("email_address1_error").firstChild.nodeValue="";
    }

     if(emailAddress2=="")
     {
        $(email_address2_error).firstChild.nodeValue="This feild is required.";
        isValid=false;
    }
    else if (emailAddress1!==emailAddress2)
    {
        $(email_address2_error).firstChild.nodeValue="The email addresses must match";
        isValid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("email_address2_error").firstChild.nodeValue="";
    }

    if(Name=="")
    {
        $("name_error").firstChild.nodeValue="This feild is required.";
        isValid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("name_error").firstChild.nodeValue="";
    }
    if(Subject=="")
    {
        $("subject_error").firstChild.nodeValue="This feild is Required";
        isValid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("subject_error").firstChild.nodeValue="";
    }
    if(Message=="")
     {
        $("message_error").firstChild.nodeValue="This feild is requried";
        isValid=false;
    }
    else
    {
        $("message_error").firstChild.nodeValue="";
    }

    if (isValid)
    {

    var mailto_link = 'mailto:' + Toemail + '?cc=' + CCemail + '&subject=' + Subject + '&body=' + Message;

    window.open('sent.html',"_self");
   win = window.open(mailto_link, 'sent.html');
        if (win && win.open && !win.closed) 
        {   
        win.close();
        }

    }   

}
window.onload=function()
{
    $("join_list").onclick=joinList;
    $("email_address1").focus();    
}
```

I have not added my CSS file because i do not think it is needed, beside i got so many rules in there it will be impossible to decipher.If you really need it, then i will post it.

Comment: Hi, to debug(ie.. find out why things 'won't work') your web pages in IE11, first go Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes. Open your dev web page, press f12 then Debug tab, then select "Break on all exceptions" from the dropdown on the debug tab. !important ... without closing the dev tool (applies to all browser dev tools) return to the browser and continue your testing.... execution will now break when errors are encountered....Include any error messages from the dev tool console tab with your questions.

Comment: The main differences between web browsers (viz IE and FX) are
1. Security settings and domain mapping to a security zone.... IE has restrictions for Intranet domains.... use the File>Properties menu to determine which IE security zone your dev domain (localhost?) is mapped to. You can assume that your final web site will automatically map to the IE Internet Zone. 2. The browser Addons model.... your testing cycle should always include running the browsers in noAddons  or InPrivate modes.